# Reversing a letter to a number if choice is selected

Tags: c++, probability, flip

TASK: Ensure there is a 30% chance for a password non-special character to be a number. (Clue: generate a random number between 0 and 3. If 0, let the character be a random number between 0 and 9).

In my code I have written HERE, this is where I am stuck.

```
#include <iostream>     //for cout, cin
#include <string>       //for string
#include <stdlib.h>     //for rand
#include <time.h>       //for time

using namespace std;
string getRandString(int N, string tokens)
{
    string randStr = "";

    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        int randIndex = rand() % tokens.length();
        randStr = tokens[randIndex] + randStr;
    }

    return randStr;
}

/*string getRandString(int stringLength)
{
    string randStr = "";
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for(int i = 0; i<stringLength; i++)
    {
        int randIndex = rand() % alphabet.length();
        randStr = alphabet[randIndex] + randStr;
    }

    return randStr;
}*/

string getNRandomSpecialChars(int N)
{
    string specialChars = "!%+-:_";
    string randStr = "";

    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        int randIndex = rand() % specialChars.length();
        randStr = specialChars[randIndex] + randStr;
    }

    return randStr;
}

int getRandomBetweenRange(int min, int max)
{
    return rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
}

string injectRandomString(string oldString, string injectionString)
{
    if( injectionString.length() == 0 )
    {
        return oldString;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<oldString.length(); i++)
    {
        int coinToss = rand() % 2;
        int randIndex = rand() % injectionString.length();

        if( coinToss == 1 )
        {
            oldString[i] = injectionString[randIndex];
        }
    }
    ///*********************** HERE ***********************
    for (int j = 0; j<oldString.length(); j++)
    {
        int flipToNum = rand() % 3;
        int randInd = rand() % injectionString.length();

        if (flipToNum == 3)
        {
            oldString[j] = ;
        }
    }

    return oldString;
}

int main()
{
    //initialize random seed
    srand (time(NULL));
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string specialChars = "!%+-:_";

    for(int j = 0; j<10; j++)
    {
        int zeroToSix = rand() % 7;

        int max = 14 + zeroToSix;
        int min = 1;

        int stringLength = getRandomBetweenRange(min, max);

        //method 1 - start

        //string password = getRandString(stringLength);
        //string specialChars = getNRandomSpecialChars(zeroToSix);

        //method 1 - end

        //method 2 - start

        string password = getRandString(stringLength, alphabet);
        string specialCharsString = getRandString(zeroToSix, specialChars);

        password = injectRandomString(password, specialCharsString);
        //method 2 - end

        cout << password << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    //cout << stringLength << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (0 == rand() % 3)` make it a number, else make it something else.

Comment: so take out what i have under 'here'

Comment: The result of `% 3` is never 3

Comment: Change `if (flipToNum == 3) { oldString[j] = ; }` to `if (flipToNum == 0) { oldString[j] = rand() % 10 + 48; }`.

Comment: may I ask why you chose 10 + 48

Comment: `rand() % 10` gives number 0-9. Adding 48 (the char code for '0') converts to a char. You could also use a string ("0123456789") like you did in other places in the code.